# How to only get the tag that has text with it in lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml, python-xmlschema

I'm using lxml and I have a xml like this:

```
<UploadFile>
<Eu>
<AUTO_ID>4</AUTO_ID>
<Meter>000413031</Meter>
</Eu>
</UploadFile>
```

How can I only get the tag that has text like AUTO_ID and Meter,but not UploadFile Eu?

I have tried:

```
    tree = lxml.etree.parse(xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()

for node in root.iter('*'):
    if node.text != None:
        print(node.tag,node.text)
```

But still I can get all the tags,I only want the tag has text with it,what can I do ?Any friend can help?Best regards!

Comment: how about like this ` if len(node.text.strip()) > 0:
        print(node.tag,node.text)' ?

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you can remove the spaces using strip() then check if len>0 or can check for none using `if node.text.strip()`

**option 1:**

```
import lxml
tree = lxml.etree.parse("my_xml.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for node in root.iter('*'):
    if len(node.text.strip()) > 0: # check if len > 0, text will have some length
        print(node.tag,node.text)
```

**option 2:**

```
import lxml
tree = lxml.etree.parse("my_xml.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for node in root.iter('*'): # checking if its None
    if node.text.strip():
        print(node.tag,node.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `xml.etree`, lxml supports more complex XPath expression including XPath that return *all descendant elements that have child text node that isn't empty or white-space-only*:

```py
    for node in root.xpath(".//*[text()[normalize-space()]]"):
        print(node.tag,node.text)
```